# How can I efficiently and easily import/export large business data in .NET?

Tags: .net, sql, xml, entity-framework, business-objects

What would be the best data format (XML, Database, etc.) for large business data when we want to efficiently and easily load all of it (import) into business objects in .NET ?

I want to load all the data in one go and create all business objects. 
The data must have a kind of a "schema" to enable other people to create it.

Also note that I want to ease the process of creating the business classes from the specific schema of the data (could be XSD schema, Database schema, etc.).
I have tried two approaches, neither of which proved entirely satisfactory :

1. **XML**, **xsd.exe** or equivalent tool (like Xsd2Code) to generate the business classes and the mapping. For large data, size of the XML store becomes an issue.
2. **Database** (SQL Server CE), leveraging the **Entity Framework** to create the business classes and the mapping : during the first tests, for increasing database size, EF was in serious trouble (performance problems and out of memory exceptions).

What I want to achieve (loading large business data into memory in one go) seems "standard" (or is it really ?), yet I can't find an efficient and clean way to do it.

Comment: A database is for **storing** (and manipulating) data - XML is great for **exchanging** data (import/export, ETL etc.). Use each as appropriate (e.g. do **not** use XML as storage)

Comment: You need a data store?  Do you even have a database set up with your data yet?

Comment: To clarify things a bit, we have tested two solutions : retrieving data from XML and from SQL Server CE file. Those files are created by other people and we need to load all the data into memory to perform computations. Perhaps the term "data store" is misleading. We are actually exchanging data.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your favorite answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually a bit vague, so I can only answer with my gut feeling. Storing data is for databases. You are talking about business objects, so using an OR/M tool is a logical pick. Since you're in .NET, Entity Framework is a logical pick.

It doesn’t seem to me that Entity Framework should cause any problems around memory that other solutions won't give you. I think your OOM problems are caused by improper use of the tool or perhaps other problems. If you're keep having problems with it, please ask a specific question about this problem, here at SO.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, I thought too that EF shouldn't cause any problems, perhaps I am misusing it. I used the EDMX designer to do the OR mapping. In the actual tests, I simply create the objectcontext and retrieve data using linq to entities, all straightforward stuff, yet I experienced performance problems.

Comment: Performance problems is possible. EF isn't the quickest of its kind, but most performance problems can be solved however. I advise you to post a concrete question (with code samples that show your problem) here at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) in the .NET framework. I'm using this with a data interchange project and .NET supports serializing and deserializing the information into and from objects with very little code. It may be the path you want to take.

Edit: I see you've played with xsd.exe as well, you could use a db to store the XML in a column in a table for easy retrieval. We're actually doing this as well in the current project. We're receiving some XML from a 3rd party source, so we store it in a table, validate it against the schema, then read it out into .NET objects generated from a .xsd file using the xsd.exe approach. I'm not sure how large your data is, but this approach works well for us.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I have tested DataContract serialization as well because it is possible to obtain a XSD schema from our business classes quite easily. As the data files are created by other people (not necessarily working with .NET), the idea was simply to provide them with the XSD file, but as mentioned XML files are not really adequate (large data) and the XSD generated  in this fashion is more complex to understand than a custom made one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have XML and SQLDatabases, you can try LINQ. Use SQLMetal program to automatically generate Classes that correspond to your SQLDatabase tables. If you have relationships in you DB they are also preserved in object model generated by SQLMetal.

Comment: Hi, this is basically what I did, letting Entity Framework generate the business classes and the OR mapping. My problem was that in my tests EF had poor performance when loading large data.